# How to delete the entire library

Tags: kodi

I have XBMC installed on a HTPC.  I use it to play the movies I have copied from my DVD collection.  I store those movies on a separate server.  I had to move the files to a different location on the server.  Now when I try to play a movie I get an error stating the file does not exist.  How can I delete the entire database in XBMC so it can rebuild itself with the new correct location of the movie files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete `MyVideos34.db` from `XBMC\userdata\Database`.

Comment: The same works on Linux with `~/.xbmc/userdata/Database/MyVideos*.db`. But note that this does not only delete the library content but also the settings for each source (whether they contain movies or series, the preferred language etc.).

Comment: And it seems like your favorites get corrupted and link to different locations after deleting and regenerating the DB :(.

Comment: this works with kodi too `~/.kodi/userdata/Satabase/MyVideos**.db`

Comment: Good luck doing this on Android TV without somekind of filesystem app...

Answer (score 7):

You could also go to Settings > Video and clean the library. That will remove any items in the library that it can no longer find on the disk, then just rescan.

I recently migrated my XBMC library from one server to another and just changed the locations in the database, but I was using MySQL, so I'm not sure how I would do the same thing in SQLite, which is the built-in database.

Mine all moved from a NFS export on one server to a CIFS share on another.

Comment: If the 'Clean library...' item is not visible, switch your 'Settings level' at the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

What version of XBMC is this?! You might need to upgrade to the latest XBMC release which is currently 11.0 (code named "Eden").

You also didn't say what OS XBMC was running on! There is a XBMCBuntu version that runs on a stripped down version of Ubuntu (Linux). Then there's the XBMC app that runs under Windows. There's still other releaes of XBMC for other OS's like Mac too. So you your problems may be completely unrelated to XBMC but rather stem with your operating system.

But frankly, I'm inclined to think this may be a Windows problem totally unrelated to XBMC.

Comment: Actually I am running the linux version. I have had it installed for a few years now.  Back then you could download an ISO directly from xbmc.org that installed everything for you.

Comment: It is related to XBMC.  When I boot the computer it automatically boots up into XBMC.  Then it starts checking for new content.  WHen it finds new content it stores that information in its own database somewhere.  I need to find out how to delete that database so it will find everything fresh again.  Then it will have the correct file path recorded in the XBMC database, wherever that may be.